# Debian install missing aqc111 driver

Tags: linux, debian, drivers, make

I'm running Debian unstable

```
# uname -srvmo
Linux 5.10.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.4-1 (2020-12-31) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and want to use a device that requires the `aqc111` driver. This driver should be included in the kernel: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.10/drivers/net/usb/aqc111.c

However, it isn't available in Debian for some reason:

```
# modinfo aqc111
modinfo: ERROR: Module aqc111 not found.
```

How can I compile and install the `aqc111` driver on my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Included in `linux-image` the name is `atlantic`  (output from debian buster):

```
$ modinfo atlantic

filename:       /lib/modules/4.19.0-13-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/aquantia/atlantic/atlantic.ko
description:    aQuantia Corporation(R) Network Driver
author:         aQuantia
version:        2.0.3.0-kern
license:        GPL v2
```

To load the driver:

```
sudo modprobe -v atlantic
```

Comment: The `aqc111` driver isn't contained in the atlantic module, perhaps because it's for usb network adapters?
I think I have to build it manually, how can I achieve this?

Comment: @morrow The driver is [available here](https://github.com/Aquantia/AQtion/) and the [instruction from here](https://github.com/Aquantia/AQtion/blob/master/README.txt)